# passing href link through angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an array of messages

```
$scope.messsages = []
```

Upon clicking a button the content of a text area gets added into the array using ng-click method.This message is used to query the api. After which we get a response from the server which too is added into the array `$scope.messages`. All these messages are shown in html using ng-repeat i.e:-

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in messages track by $index">
  {{ msg }}
</div>
```

However if I get a response from the server as a hyperlink string like

`To know more <a href="URL">click here</a>`.

The message that gets displayed in ng-repeat is a plain string with no hyperlinks. It renders the `<a href="URL">` part as a string itself. I would like to represent it in html format.

One way it worked was by using

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $scope.messages;
```

But I would like to know is there any angular way to do so in the `ng-repeat` part itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try use `ng-bind-html` for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ng-bind-html` for this. so you should inject `ngSanitize` in your `app`.

```
$scope.html = '<a href="#/Test">test</a>';
$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
```

```js
angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('main', function($scope,$sce) {
   $scope.messages = [{"link":"<a href='#/abc'>abc</a>"}];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="main">    
  <div ng-repeat="msg in messages">
      <div ng-bind-html="msg.link"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please illustrate with an example in ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in messages track by $index">
    <div ng-bind-html="msg"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/9aT4IPgzJKq32KTEDB1b?p=preview) example for it.

Answer (score 1):

Include ngSanitize module on your app and then change your view as below

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in messages track by $index">
    <div ng-bind-html="msg"></div>
</div>
```